# How to Close an ActiveXObject Application

Tags: javascript, activexobject

I m pretty new to JavaScript... 
I have launched a 3rd party application from Javascript using ActiveXObject.
But I m not able to terminate this application from JS. Can anybody help me ??
Excerpt from code..

```
  var App = new ActiveXObject("MyApp.Application");
  App.Show(true);
  App.OpenProject(ProjectFilePath)
  .......
  .......
  App.CloseProject();
  App.Exit() // This line gives error and doesnt close the Application.
```

I have even tried `App.Application.Quit(), App.Quit(), App.Close()`. But none of these are working.